# How can I get the MSE of a tensor across a specific dimension?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, mean-square-error

I have 2 tensors with `.size` of `torch.Size([2272, 161])`. I want to get mean-squared-error between them. However, I want it along each of the 161 channels, so that my error tensor has a `.size` of `torch.Size([161])`. How can I accomplish this?

It seems that `torch.nn.MSELoss` doesn't let me specify a dimension.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the `nn.MSELoss` you can specify the option `reduction='none'`. This then gives you back the squared error for each entry position of both of your tensors. Then you can apply torch.sum/torch.mean.

```
a = torch.randn(2272,161)
b = torch.randn(2272,161)
loss = nn.MSELoss(reduction='none')
loss_result = torch.sum(loss(a,b),dim=0)
```

I don't think there is a direct way to specify at the initialisation of the loss to which dimension to apply mean/sum. Hope that helps!